# Cap deploy failing - rvm path is incorrect

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rvm, capistrano

Here's what I get why I do a cap deploy
`** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::CommandError, failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p327@faxattach' -c 'rm -rf /srv/faxattach/releases/20130703184411; true'" on faxattach-staging-new
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p327@faxattach' -c 'git clone -q git@github.com:chintanparikh/faxattach.git /srv/faxattach/releases/20130703184411 && cd /srv/faxattach/releases/20130703184411 && git checkout -q -b deploy a237b155f1fe4acef23ad4b594749c567a213117 && (echo a237b155f1fe4acef23ad4b594749c567a213117 > /srv/faxattach/releases/20130703184411/REVISION)'" on faxattach-staging-new`

It looks like the issue is in rvm_path. My rvm path is `/usr/local/rvm`, but I'm not sure how to change that -

Here's my deploy.rb in my sinatra app:

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'rvm/capistrano'

set :stages, %w(production staging development)
set :default_stage, "staging"

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p327@faxattach'
set :rvm_type, :user

# Bundler tasks
# require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :application, 'faxattach'
set :apikey, 'MHaBUh3Kctz2x500l5LPMFjo9LNLDKfl6EHF69C1Fq2WrIuB66yw6k5xj30dI17IZ'
set :ssh_options, {forward_agent: true}
# do not use sudo
set :use_sudo, false
set(:run_method) { use_sudo ? :sudo : :run }

# # needed to correctly handle sudo password prompt
default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :user, 'faxattach'
set :group, 'faxattach'
set :runner, 'faxattach'

# Where will it be located on the server?
set :deploy_to, "/srv/#{application}"
set :unicorn_conf, "#{deploy_to}/current/config/unicorn.rb"
set :unicorn_pid, "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Unicorn control tasks
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && [ -e /proc/`cat #{unicorn_pid}` ]; then kill -USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; else cd #{deploy_to}/current && API_KEY=#{apikey} bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D; fi"
  end
  task :start do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D"
  end
  task :end do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ]; then kill -QUIT `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; fi"
  end
end
```

Any ideas how I'd change the rvm path?

Comment: Is RVM working other ways? Have you got something like `## RVM
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in your `.bashrc`?
`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue by setting the `:rvm_type` to `:system`:

```
set :rvm_type, :system
```

Comment: `set :rvm_type, :user` is prefered